# PHP Echo syntax error with single quote or double quotes?

Tags: php

The is a very simple echo statement but I can't solve it?

```
echo '"What is your name?'";
```

Comment: Why does stuff like this get voted down?

Comment: @Precision I can't really see how this question could help anyone else. What would they search for to find this? *"my code is wrong"*? Even rewording the question to make it useful is pointless. If someone knew what to search for (eg "mismatched quotes"), then they would have already solved their problem. Even the most basic of debugging (eg *just looking at your syntax highlighting*) would show the error here. We all have dumb errors like this which you can't figure out straight away, and I don't think there's anything wrong with asking it, but it's pretty obvious why it'd get voted down.

Comment: @nickf I agree, but the answerers seem to enjoy this one, so I gave it my best shot as a title edit

Comment: @Jeff you've made it much worse. Because there are very popular terrible rumor about a question you made a title. While the question itself was about syntax error, not quote styles.

Comment: @col good point, I added "syntax error"

Comment: Dude, if there's nothing wrong with asking it, then I certainly can't understand why it'd be voted down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "What is your name?";
```

This is Simply the best. No confusion No problem..:)

Answer (score 24):

Mismatch of single quotes, use this:

```
echo '"What is your name?"';
```

Your first enclosing character was single quote but ending one was double quote causing the problem

Answer (score 9):

Incorrect:

```
echo '"What is your name?'";
                          ^ Unexpected character
```

Correct:

```
echo '"What is your name?';
```

Correct:

```
echo "What is your name?";
```

Correct:

```
echo 'What is your name?';
```

Correct:

```
echo '"What is your name?"';
```

Correct:

```
echo "'What is your name?'";
```

Comment: @Sarfraz - how do you figure that? How do you know he doesn't want the single quotes in the string?

Comment: @nickf: I did not say he doesn't want single quotes, I meant he needs his string inside the double quotes something that can be seen from his code, only that he placed ending single quotes wrongly, basically he seems to echo it like this `"What is  your name?"`, see double quotes included in the *output*. Something that can be figured out from his code `'"What is your name?"';`

Comment: @sarfraz: `only that he placed ending single quotes wrongly` .. or the starting single quotes were placed wrongly...

Answer (score 6):

Your quotes are nested incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "\"What is your name?\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where your interpreter is choking:

echo '"What is your name?'`";`

expecting `;` not `"`